# What makes an Ultra Ball different from the basic Poké Ball?

Tags: pokemon

> The Ultra Ball (Japanese: ハイパーボール Hyper Ball) has a 100% higher chance to catch a Pokémon than a regular Poké Ball, and a 33% higher chance than a Great Ball. It has a catch multiplier of 2.0.

[image: The Poké Ball, Great Ball, Ultra Ball, and Master Ball]

What is the factor that makes Poké Balls such as the Ultra Ball and many others different from regular Poké Balls?

Comment: The technology that goes into improving the catch rate? Anyway, the numbers in your quote most likely comes from the game.

Comment: While I want to know myself, I voted to close. I don't think the reason as to why they can catch pokemon better was never explained, not in the games, manga, nor even in the anime. Heck I don't even think the mechanism is explained at all (could be wrong on that one though).

Comment: As my own speculation, I'd say it has something to do with the closing mechanism. As we can see in the manga, the shutter can be damaged, preventing the pokeballs from opening and trapping the pokemon inside until it's repaired. The shutter is key to catching/trapping a pokemon in the ball. It might thus be the case that the ultra ball has a more advanced/stronger lock than the pokeball, making it harder for the pokemon to open the lock and escape from the ball. With the masterball having the perfect lock, as not even Mewtwo could open that ball after being caught by Red at almost full power.

Comment: Hmm .. I suppose I have to improve the question . But @PeterRaeves your comment should be posted as an answer . Its good :D

Comment: This should not be closed. Just because we *think* there *likely* is not an answer within canon, doesn't mean we can say for sure whether or not that is the case. The answer could be in an interview that we have not encountered; it is pure speculation of us to suggest there is no canon answer.

Comment: Well there isn't really an explanation. The only different thing is the catch rate, which can be put in some formular to calculate the chance of catching a Pokemon, but the exact question why wasn't asked yet. And, and this is my opinion, since there are no real Pokemons and no real Pokeballs I don't think somebody cared why they catch the way they do. Well except you.

Comment: @EroSennin Ah well in that case, sorry for my statement. Didn't intent to insult you or your interests in any kind. Dx

Comment: @EroSennin Good, thanks. xD Added a bounty, I'd like to know a possible answer aswell now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is based on canon facts, but, as far as I know, I don't think the mechanism was ever explained. The [wiki on the Poke Ball mechanism](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball#Mechanics_and_design) agrees that the mechanism is unknown so far.

[image: enter image description here!]

As my own speculation, I'd say it might have something to do with the closing mechanism. As we can see in chapter 38, Giovanni damaged Red's Poke Balls' shutters during his gym fight, preventing the Poke Balls from opening and trapping Gyarados and Venusaur inside until the balls were repaired. The shutter must be key to catching/trapping a Pokemon in the ball. It might thus be the case that Ultra Ball has a more advanced or stronger lock than a regular Poke Ball, making it harder for the Pokemon to open the lock and escape from the ball. With the Master Ball having the perfect lock, as not even Mewtwo could escape after being caught by Red, in chapter 35, while still being at almost full power.

[image: enter image description here!]

As we can see, the Poke Balls are empty inside. The only thing it seemingly does is shrink the Pokemon. There is no inducing gas or anything inside to weaken the Pokemon. Pokemon do undergo a change in character when being caught though. We have seen the most bad-ass Pokemon turn into loyal *servants/friends* after being caught. But this might be due to the Pokemon's honour submitting to its defeat, or it might be that the Poke Ball actually does something to the Pokemon during the bounce process. We don't really know the correct answer to this so far. Again, Mewtwo could be seen as a good example, as he didn't start rampaging after being released from his ball, but he came to respect his trainer Blaine.

Answer (score -2):

This video explains how Pokeballs work in the best way I've seen: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvCZNEsld54

Comment: In its current form, this is effectively a link-only answer, which is discouraged on Stack Exchange. (Links can disappear over time, and in that case, the value of the post will be lost.) Could you perhaps summarize in your post the key points from the video that you thought were important?